# how to insert into (tb1) from (tb2) another table with spesific multiple where clause

Tags: mysql

i have insert row 1 - 3000 ++ row with using this query example below :

```
INSERT INTO _tb_email_kirul SELECT * FROM tb_email_1708 WHERE card_no = '4890-8700-5889-4693';
INSERT INTO _tb_email_kirul SELECT * FROM tb_email_1708 WHERE card_no = '4890-8700-5712-0546';
INSERT INTO _tb_email_kirul SELECT * FROM tb_email_1708 WHERE card_no = '4890-8700-5566-8710';
INSERT INTO _tb_email_kirul SELECT * FROM tb_email_1708 WHERE card_no = '4890-8700-5262-5382';
INSERT INTO _tb_email_kirul SELECT * FROM tb_email_1708 WHERE card_no = '4890-8700-5879-5643';
INSERT INTO _tb_email_kirul SELECT * FROM tb_email_1708 WHERE card_no = '4890-8700-5247-8618';
+++++
```

i has try data insert from 1 - 3000++ and take 1 hours to finish it.

can this query take a single query or faster than my query ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IN` to combine the queries.

```
INSERT INTO _tb_email_kirul
SELECT * FROM tb_email_1708
WHERE card_no IN ('4890-8700-5889-4693', '4890-8700-5712-0546',... )
```